# IIS: Manipulate X-Forwarded-for header

Tags: http, iis, x-forwarded-for

Is it possible to change the X-Forwarded-For header of incoming requests, so that only the rightmost IP address is kept?

Example:

`173.8.159.11, 164.214.214.90`

Becomes

`164.214.214.90`

Answer (score 0):

The IP address on the right is the IP address of the proxy server, and the IP address on the far left is the IP address of the original client. According to the description, you want to keep only the rightmost IP address. If it is for the purpose of not exposing the client IP, you can directly use the browser plug-in to modify and disguise X-Forwarded-For (XFF) to achieve any IP. Because, as far as security is concerned, XFF is easily forged and should not be relied upon for serious purposes.